# Paintbrush-like textured strokes in WPF

Tags: wpf, textures, lines, brushes

I need a way to draw lines in WPF that have a rough, textured or distressed effect, as if they've been drawn by a real brush or pen stroke. I can go some way to doing what I want using graphic elements but this approach doesn't scale very well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can done it by processing pixels in bitmap
using a for-loop get pixels from brush-bitmap
and started another for-loop to set pixels on destinate bitmap

i've already done it once, but it's really a hard way